# SQL Data Type for System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I want to save a setting in MS SQL for .net Color.  What data type in MS SQL should I use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `Int32`, then use `Color.FromArgb(Int32)` and `Color.ToArgb()` to read and write, respectively. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed705s37.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The easy way would be to use [color.ToArgb()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb.aspx) to convert it to a 32-bit integer and store it as that. You can convert it back to a color using the static method [Color.FromArgb(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You should use `int`.  I would have stopped there but I need to have at least 30 characters.

Comment: :-) Or you could let the user have any colour. As long as it's green.

Answer (score 2):

I'd store it as an `INT` because technically that is what it is.